# String replace with strange characters when attributed to a HASH

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I'm testing 2 situations and getting 2 strangely different results.

First:

```
hash_data_file = CSV.parse(data_file).map {|line|
    puts line[6]
    abort
```

The return is `Caixa Econômica Federal` with accents in the right place.

Second:

```
hash_data_file = CSV.parse(data_file).map {|line|
    puts :bank => line[6]
    abort
```

But the return is `{:bank=>"Caixa Econ\xC3\xB4mica Federal"}`, a string with errors in the codification instead of the accents.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no “error in codification.”

```
"Caixa Econ\xC3\xB4mica Federal" == "Caixa Econômica Federal"
#⇒ true
```

For some reason when printing out a hash, ruby uses this representation (I cannot reproduce it though,) but in a nutshell the string you see is good enough.

Comment: Reproducing the problem is easy, just get the data into binary encoding. And `"Caixa Econ\xC3\xB4mica Federal".force_encoding('binary') == "Caixa Econômica Federal"` isn't true so you need to be careful.

Comment: @muistooshort of course enforcing encoding would make them differ, but it is slightly unfair to enforce it here and not there. And `"Caixa Econ\xC3\xB4mica Federal".force_encoding('binary') == "Caixa Econômica Federal".force_encoding('binary')` is still surely `true`.

Comment: My point is that the string that Ruby is showing with the hex codes has a difference that isn't immediately apparent so a simple `==` test papers over the underlying problem. i.e. `"Caixa Econ\xC3\xB4mica Federal"` already has binary encoding, `"Caixa Econômica Federal"` already has UTF-8 encoding so we need to be careful of the hidden bits.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, your `data_file` is in UTF-8 encoding. In the second case, `data_file` has binary (i.e. 7-bit ASCII) encoding.

For example, if we start with a simple UTF-8 CSV file:

```
bank
Caixa Econômica Federal
```

and then parse it with UTF-8 encoding:

```
CSV.parse(File.open('pancakes.csv', encoding: 'utf-8'))
# [["bank"], ["Caixa Econômica Federal"]]
```

and then in binary encoding:

```
CSV.parse(File.open('pancakes.csv', encoding: 'binary'))
# [["bank"], ["Caixa Econ\xC3\xB4mica Federal"]]
```

So you need to fix the encoding by reading the file in the proper encoding. Hard to say more since we don't know how `data_file` is being opened.

Have a look at

```
line[6].encoding
```

and you should see `#<Encoding:UTF-8>` in the first case but `#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>` in the second.